# Node.js: console.err() is syncronous or asyncronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I use AWS and I want write all errors to `stderr` using `console.err()`. `stderr` is caught by **AWS Cloud Watch** and logged. I don't want blocking the event loop.

Is `console.err()` in Node.js implementation asynchronous?

Comment: Why does it matter? Logging is probably not the bottleneck of your application.

Comment: A portion of `console.xxx()` is synchronous and blocking and once the data is delivered to another thread, the rest is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS and of where `stderr` is "going".

From [the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o):

> `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` differ from other Node.js streams in important ways:
>
> 1. They are used internally by `console.log()` and `console.error()`, respectively.
> 2. Writes may be synchronous depending on what the stream is connected to and whether the system is Windows or POSIX:
>
>    - Files: synchronous on Windows and POSIX
>    - TTYs (Terminals): asynchronous on Windows, synchronous on POSIX
>    - Pipes (and sockets): synchronous on Windows, asynchronous on POSIX

Answer (score 1):

For educational purpose I am going to demonstrate how to check it so you don't need to ask next time.
This is how you test if the code is async in the most basic case:

```js
const asyncOperation = async () => {
 await new Promise( (res) => setTimeout(res, 1000))
 console.log("Async finished")
}

console.log("Start")
asyncOperation()
console.log("End")
```

So if you run it you will see it prints "End" first and then later it prints "Async finished", because setTimeout is asynchronous.

So I will add new snipped for your case, so you know.

```js
const asyncOperation = () => {
  console.error("Async Err?")
}

console.log("Start")
asyncOperation()
console.log("End")
```

Run it and you'll see. You can also try it out in Node environment, the result would be the same.

And listen to @jonas-wilms he is right, Logging is pretty fast